# Nexus 4 problems connecting usb mtp

Tags: nexus-4, usb-connection-mode

I recently bought a Nexus 4 and I encountered a real issue with my computer (Windows 8 Pro 64 Bit) not being able to connect in USB mode. It does however work with Camera PTP mode, which I find very strange.

I have tried/tested with:

1. Different usb cables
2. My computer with the same OS of Windows 8 64 bit isn't connecting compared to another computer with the same OS.
3. Removing its current drivers on my computer and reinstalling drivers from [Nexus 4 ToolKit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1995688)
4. Restarting the computer
5. With/without USB debugging mode

Note that the device is visible on the computer although it's not recognized:

[image: Nexus 4 not recognized]

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Stock ROM?

Comment: Just got it not rooted yet can't even connect to my PC to root this thing.

Comment: Try the [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/). Also see: [Transfer files to Nexus 4](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45244/16575) and [Mount a Kindle Fire](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39502/16575) (though a different device, steps are comparable).

Comment: Also see: [Why does the manta (nexus 10) not “mount” with MTP selected?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43034/16575) / [Nexus 7 won't show up as a drive on Windows in MTP mode after update to Android 4.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35635/16575) / [File transfer between Windows 8 and Nexus 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47316/16575) / [Unable to connect my Nexus 7 to a PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36157/16575) / [How can I troubleshoot MTP on my Galaxy Nexus](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46958/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Universal ADB driver I have tested and tried no luck. The other links are for different OS systems which doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: I remember we had this issue already with Windows 8 (that user had no trouble with Win7, but only with Win8) -- and if I remember correctly, the universal driver solved the issue for him. Just cannot remember wich question that was... OK, sorry it didn't help. Not having any windows other than those to let light and air into my house, I'm afraid I can not further assist you.

Comment: You tried your best. I looked into most of the question and answers with no avail. I know the cause is not my phone, it's windows end with an MTP issue.

Comment: related: [Android 5.0 Lollipop device not detected via USB](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb).

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 8.1 and I had the same problem, PTP working, MTP not. I was following the steps suggested in [this page](http://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/1k1akl/nexus_4_not_showing_up_as_a_media_device/) but it wasn't doing the job, until I made some previous steps, and slightly changed the last part. Summarising what I did is:

1. Connect your device.
2. Unistall ALL the drivers from the Device Manager, be sure to go in "View"->"Show hidden devices" and then check that all of the following are unistalled:

   **a)** Android Devices

   **b)** Other devices

   **c)** Portable interfaces
3. Now disconnect your device.
4. Check the PTP mode and connect your device. Wait for the drivers to be installed.
5. Without disconnecting check the MTP mode on your device and wait the drivers to be installed again.

Now it should WORK!! At least it did it for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just :

1. Deleting Acer Adb Interface not just Uninstalling it
2. Disconnected my Phone and then connected it back
3. Waited for drivers to be installed.

Then the pc recognizes it, in  Usb Mode not as a ADB interface.

Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are expecting mass storage USB mode which is not supported with Nexus4 (stock android)

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer, and provide a reference showing that it's not supported?